# zurb jquery serp tool html().replace

Tags: jquery, input, onload

I am using Zurb Foundation and I am looking at making a SERP preview tool for my CMS I am creating.

First of all I realize I am mixing Javascript with JQuery but that is because I could not get a basic JQuery alert working without putting it in the js/app.js file and then it would not let me select element by id. So I have enclosed the JQuery inside a javascript onload function and it works fine.

The script finds the focus keyword from the input and bolds all the matching words in the SERP preview. This all works fine, except when I create a new focus keyword the it bolds all the new matching words but keeps bold all of the old matching words.

For instance if my description was "Test me" and the focus keyword is "test" then it will show as "**Test** me". If i change the focus keyword to me it will display as "**Test me**" not "Test **me**".

Here is my code

```
<script>
function updateSerpTool() {

        var focusKeyword = $('#form_sc_focus_keyword').val();
        var re = new RegExp(focusKeyword,"ig");

        $('#title_result:contains("' + focusKeyword + '")').each(function(){
            $('#title_result').html( 
                $('#title_result').html().replace(re,'<strong>$&</strong>')
            );
        });
        $('#description_result:contains("' + focusKeyword + '")').each(function(){
            $('#description_result').html( 
                $('#description_result').html().replace(re,'<strong>$&</strong>')
            );
        });
        $('#sub:contains("' + focusKeyword + '")').each(function(){
            $('#sub').html( 
                $('#sub').html().replace(re,'<strong>$&</strong>')
            );
        });
    }
window.onload = function() {
    /*
     * Look for change in inputs and update SERP Tool
    */
    updateSerpTool();
    $('#form_sc_name').change(function() {
        $('#title_result').html($(this).val());
        updateSerpTool();
    })
    $('#form_sc_meta_desc').change(function() {
        $('#description_result').html($(this).val());
        updateSerpTool();
    })
    $('#form_sc_focus_keyword').change(function() {
        updateSerpTool();
    })
};
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot to say. I did try using: $('#sub').css("font-weight", "normal"); but it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this like so:
Next i'll look at running each word through an array to check and tidy it all up. Thanks anyway.

```
<script>
function updateSerpTool() {

        var focusKeyword = $('#form_sc_focus_keyword').val();
        var re = new RegExp(focusKeyword,"ig");
        $('#title_result').html($('#title_result').text());
        $('#description_result').html($('#description_result').text());
        $('#sub').html($('#sub').text());

        $('#title_result:contains("' + focusKeyword + '")').each(function(){
            $('#title_result').html( 
                $('#title_result').text().replace(re,'<strong>$&</strong>')
            );
        });
        $('#description_result:contains("' + focusKeyword + '")').each(function(){
            $('#description_result').html( 
                $('#description_result').text().replace(re,'<strong>$&</strong>')
            );
        });
        $('#sub:contains("' + focusKeyword + '")').each(function(){
            $('#sub').html( 
                $('#sub').text().replace(re,'<strong>$&</strong>')
            );
        });
    }
window.onload = function() {
    /*
     * Look for change in inputs and update SERP Tool
    */
    updateSerpTool();
    $('#form_sc_name').change(function() {
        $('#title_result').html($(this).val());
        updateSerpTool();
    })
    $('#form_sc_meta_desc').change(function() {
        $('#description_result').html($(this).val());
        updateSerpTool();
    })
    $('#form_sc_focus_keyword').change(function() {
        updateSerpTool();
    })
};
</script>
```